# How to output the sequence '1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0...' in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, sequence

I'm currently beginning to program with Java. I tried to code the sequence in the title as an output in Java, but I'm stuck! I'm experimenting with the for function, any help is welcomed ;)

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. Don't forget to indent it by four spaces so Stack Overflow will format it correctly.

Comment: Hang on, it looks a bit like a function :-)

Comment: And the language isn't called "JAVA".

Comment: Is the string of digits in the question the full output, or does the sequence need to keep going for some duration?

Comment: is it a typo or is it 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0? is it  1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 instead?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
System.out.println("1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0");
```

But seriously, folks, this is an untested first pass:

```
for(int i=1; i<100; i++){
    System.out.print("1 ");
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        System.out.print("0 ");
    }
}
```

If you looking for basic info on how to get started, Google is your friend. For example, try googling for "for loop java" and you'll get a lot of good examples. Also, to learn basic things in any language, a google search for "<language> hello world" is very reliable.

Comment: Lol, you repeated what I first thought when I saw the title of this question. (`System.out.println("1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0");`)

Answer (score 20):

Why two loops?

*(converted from C#, pardon any syntax errors)*

```
String s = "1 ";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  s = s + "0 ";
  System.out.print(s);
}
```

Self-critique:

- two for loops (like Michael Haren's solution) would negate the string copying
- a StringBuffer/StringBuilder would negate the string copying

Comment: I had to think about 5 seconds before I got it ;)

Comment: Huh? Won't this just print a single "1" followed by a growing number of zeroes? I spent more than 5 seconds reading it ...

Comment: bad karma for using String + String in loop. this algorithm has a O(n²) runtime due to object allocation/deacllocation, compared to the other solutions.

Comment: @Andreas, you're right.  But I did note, myself, that the string copying was not ideal.  I think we can all agree this was a somewhat contrived requirement.  I just liked this as an alternative because it uses only one for loop and the others earlier on all used two. :)

@unwind, if you doubt it debug it. :)  It performs exactly to his requirements because s starts with "1 ", and s is both appended to and printed inside the for loop.

So what's worse in this case, a known-quantity of String + String copying, or using regular expressions, or a StringBuffer, or...?

Comment: +1 The above post (@MichaelHaren) is funny, but this is a lot more fun outside-the-box way. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could store the number 10 in a variable, then in a loop print the number, multiply it by 10 (which appends a zero to its decimal representation), and repeat.

Comment: Clever--I like that idea

Comment: Right up until the point where you overflow :-)

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think he needs to print the spaces in between each digit. @Pax: This won't overflow.  He's not trying to print out the entire number, just chunks of it at a time.

Comment: Depends on when the sequence runs out, @Bill, once you get beyond 2^31 with your multiplications, you're toasted. If Q'er is stopping at 100,000 then it's okay.

Comment: It will overflow when you multiply 10^19 by 10 (assuming numbers are 64-bit). Tim's solution would last a bit longer.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  I'm assuming the string in the question is the full output.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 2; i < 64; i <<= 1)
    //System.out.print(Integer.toString(i, 2));
    System.out.print(Integer.toString(i, 2).replaceAll("[01]", "$0 "));
```

Comment: Clever.  And the spaces between chars?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Or did your teacher ask you to?
Two nested for loops will do the trick.

Or in another way in another language (Ruby):

```
4.times {|n| print 10**(n+1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a question of fors but rather of very rudimentary algorithmic thinking. 
You have a sequence that consists of a "1", and then something else that grows over time", another "1", another something, etc. You can think of these as two different series that are interleaved.

Hence, overall structure would be something like:

```
while(... infinity?)
{
   System.out.print("1");
   doSomething(); 
}
```

Now the something clearly is correlated to the number of iterations ("stages") of the outer loop or the count of 1, so you need something like:

```
int stage=0;
while(...infinity?)
{
   ++stage;
   System.out.print("1");
   for(int i=0; i<stage; ++i) System.out.print("0");
}
```

If you know how many cycles you need to go through, use a for loop instead of a while, and increase stage through it.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100000;)
{
    i = i * 10;
    System.out.print(i);              
}
```

or

```
int i = 1;

while (i < 100000)
{
    i = i * 10;
    System.out.print(i);
}
```